# position:sticky on horizontal scroll doesn't work

Tags: html, css, position, sticky, horizontal-scrolling

i have a table that looks like this:

```
<table id="navbar"  border="1" style="background-color:navy;height:150px;position:sticky;top:0px;right:0px;left:0px;border-style: solid;border-color:black;max-width:999999px; width:100%; background-image: none;">
```

the style for all tables:

```
table{
            text-align:center;
            width:30%;
            left:25%;

            /*font-size:larger;*/
        }
```

the psoition sticky should make it so that the table will always remain at the top of the screen, even on horizontall scroll. yet it doesn't work. the only way i found for it to work was by adding another table above and giving both the display:inline-table attribute, but it is not the solution i am looking for.
anyone knows the reason for why it doesn't work?

edit-i need to use position:sticky. it works pefectly for vertical scroll, but not for horizontal scroll. that is the problem i need to fix

Answer (score 2):

Sorry it took so long for someone to answer you @Erel.

So you don't have to read my ramblings if you just want code, I'll start with the demo: https://codepen.io/NerdyDeeds/pen/oNYVLpB

There's a couple things to note here, for the behavior you're after:

1. Much like the whole `height:100%` thing, for this to work, the measurements need to go all the way down to the `:root`. That is to say, every DOM node hierarchy needs to know the actual limits of its bounding box (don't worry: it'll become more clear below).
2. When an object is positioned sticky, it basically has TWO sets of coordinate limitations: those of the viewport, AND those of its parent. If the parent is `500px` wide and you scroll `1500px` off screen to the right, the sticky element will stop at the edge of its parent, not continue to tag along. Which brings us nicely to the most important aspect:
3. The `<body>` tag is simply another block-level container object, only it gets an implicit `min-width:100vw; min-height:100vh`. That said, if the one of IT'S children that's necessitating the horizontal scroll is, say, `250vw` wide, it will expand to contain that element, **but it's measurement `width` remains the same**; it's children still think papa's only `100vw` wide. Likewise, were you to explicitly *tell* it that it's "ACTUAL" width is really only 100vw, it too, will slide off-screen when scrolling, carrying its sticky child (aren't they all?) with it.

   ***The same thing applies to all the ancestral containers of your sticky element.*** They DON'T automatically get the `min-width`, so you need to explain to them they're to take up that full space. If you want that done dynamically, you need to explain that to the  `<body>`, so they can inherit the "real" `100%` of the page. If *any* ancester is throttled in its movement or its dimensions, that will cascade all the way down-chain to your element, sticky or not.

The simplest way to tackle this I've found is to simply add:

```css
    body {
        width: max-content;
    }
```

...to you CSS. This tells the body "you're actually as wide as your widest contents... pass it on!" The "cascading" portion of the CSS will take hold and carry they measurement all the way up to your sticky element, *provided none of the parent nodes between it and the body themselves are constrained* (like if you set a `width:100vw` in there somewhere. `100%` will work fine, but again: only if none of IT'S ancestors is smaller).

Check out the attached CodePen. I tried to make it as self-explanatory as I could.

[image: Screenshots of CodePen in action]

And again: sorry nobody got back to you sooner. That's a frustrating feeling that stinks. I hope you already found your solution, but if not, this may help who comes googling after. Hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

Use fixed position:

```
<table id="navbar"  border="1" style="background-color:navy;height:150px;position:fixed;top:0px;right:0px;left:0px;border-style: solid;border-color:black;max-width:999999px; width:100%; background-image: none;">
```

**position: fixed** always fixates an element to some position within its scrolling container or the viewport. No matter how you scroll its container, it will remain in the exact same position and not affect the flow of other elements within the container.

**position: sticky** basically acts like position: relative until an element is scrolled beyond a specific offset, in which case it turns into position: fixed, causing the element to "stick" to its position instead of being scrolled out of view.

Comment: i already know about position:fixed, but i need to use position:sticky.

Comment: In that case, you need another element to make it relatively fixed.

Comment: can you please give a code example? i didn't understand your solution.

Comment: did you mean that i need a fixed positioned element near it?